# making modifications in UIKit.h

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

In c and c++ languages we can able to modify the header files like stdio.h, iostream.h etc... whether it is possible to make modifications in UIKit.h. If it is possible means how make this modifications.i am new to iphone developement so i dont know about these concepts.

Comment: No note possible.. apple will reject your app. if u modified its private api.

Comment: Modifying standard header files is crazy, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @rkloves and zoul: i am trying for this just to see how this header file is coded and from that i will try to get some interesting things.

Comment: why do you want to change the header files of a library that you have no control of? that makes no sense. I can't see any reason for doing this.

Comment: @rkloves apple will not reject an app that has been messed up in this way (unless you insert your entire program in the headers). These are just headers and do not change the private api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not making any mistake , the framework has all files locked means all files are in readonly mode.

So there is not any option to change those files provided by uikit framework.

If you want to see, just goto framework folder in the xcode , then check it.

Comment: i know that the files are locked. if it is not locked means i will not raise this question here. Is there is any other way to edit the header file.

Comment: I don't think so..As you can not make any changes in any way then how to change the same.

Comment: You can use sudo and change the permissions of the headers on the command line to allow you to edit them. This sounds crazy though.

Answer (score 1):

You can not edit files but you can use Categories and Extensions as an alternative way.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html